# Exposing Meteor's mongo DB to a stateless client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I need a legacy java application to pull information from a meteor's collection.
Ideally, I would need a simple service where my app would be able to download the latest list of items prices. A scenario like going on (through an http GET):

```
www.mystore.com/listOfPrices
```

would return a json with an array

```
[{"item":"beer", price:"2.50"}, {"item":"water":, price:"1"}]
```

The problem is that I cannot make a meteor page printing the result "as is" because meteor assumes the client supports javascript. Note that I do plan to implement the java DDP client in a latter stage but here I would like to start with a very simple service.

Idea: I thought of doing my own Node.js request aside of the running meteor service in order to retrieve a snapshot of the collection. Then this request would be using a [server based javascript DDP client](https://github.com/mondora/ddp.js) in order to subscribe and filter to then return the collection once loaded as a jSON document (array).

Any idea on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to provide a REST interface. See the [MeteorPedia page on REST](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API) for how to expose collection data. It might be as simple as

```
prices = new Mongo.Collection('prices');

// Add access points for `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`
HTTP.publish({collection: prices}, function (data) {
  // here you have access to this.userId, this.query, this.params
  return prices.find({});
});
```